# "Crop" a TikZ figure used in a texte

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to crop the following TikZ figures, and also to center the figure regarding the baseline.

[image]

Here is my starting code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
          
\newcommand\parallelogram[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[xslant=1]
    \draw[->](0,0) -- (0,0.5);
    \draw[->](0,0) -- (0.75,0);
    \draw(0.75,0) -- (0.75,0.5);
    \draw(0,0.5) -- (0.75,0.5);
    \node[below] at (0.25,0) {\tiny$\vec{#1}$};
    \node[left] at (0,0.35) {\tiny$\vec{#2}$};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

$Area \left( \parallelogram{u}{v} \right) = \dots$

$Area \left( \parallelogram{a}{b} \right) = \dots$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
          
\newcommand\parallelogram[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[xslant=1,
  baseline=(current bounding box)]  % <--------------
    \draw[->](0,0) -- (0,0.5);
    \draw[->](0,0) -- (0.75,0);
    \draw(0.75,0) -- (0.75,0.5);
    \draw(0,0.5) -- (0.75,0.5);
    \node[below] at (0.25,0) {\tiny$\vec{#1}$};
    \node[left] at (0,0.35) {\tiny$\vec{#2}$};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

$Area \left( \parallelogram{u}{v} \right) = \dots$

$Area \left( \parallelogram{a}{b} \right) = \dots$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! One new thing learned.